# Iam trying to connect my android application and my django server for sending data from androiod application to django server but an error is occured

Tags: python, java, android, django

```
2023-03-12 11:22:06.372 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.372 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException(NetworkUtility.java:173)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.372 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:145)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.372 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.372 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.372 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.372 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.372 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:517)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.372 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:577)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.373 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1203)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.373 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:143)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.373 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.373 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.373 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.373 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.373 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.373 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.373 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.373 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.373 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:262)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.373 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.createOutputStream(HurlStack.java:319)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.373 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBody(HurlStack.java:301)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.373 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:285)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.373 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:257)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.373 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:89)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.373 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:104)
2023-03-12 11:22:06.373 26197-26197/com.example.demo_app_java W/System.err:     ... 3 more
```

Connection between android app and django n
server

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added a link at the top of your question. Hopefully it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it to IO I never heard of a socket that is.net it could be wrong but as far as I understand this I'll so just put java.io